# Unable to install React on Mac using npm

Tags: reactjs, macos, npm, installation, terminal

I have tried installing the command `npm install -g create-react-app`
But i get an error like this

```
Ahamad@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % node -v
v16.15.0
Ahamad@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm -v
8.5.5
Ahamad@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro ~ % npm install -g create-react-app
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ahamad/.npm/_logs/2022-05-15T16_46_06_712Z-debug-0.log
Ahamad@MacBooks-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Comment: Welcome Ahamed. Have you confirmed that your Mac user account is an admin?

Comment: Btw Dan's answer below is correct, you shouldn't be installing this package globally - instead you should use npx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to install this?

If you have npm and node installed you need to simply run the following command in the folder where you wish to create your project.

Note the NPX and not NPM at the start, this isn't a mistake

```
npx create-react-app <your app name here>
```

For more information see [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding sudo in front of your command ?

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command first to rectify files ownership under /usr/local :

```
sudo chown -R $(id -un):$(id -gn) /usr/local/*
```

then rerun `npm install...`